# ASP.NET Web Forms + jQuery

Tags: jquery, webforms, unobtrusive-javascript

So, I have been programming with ASP.NET MVC with jQuery for quite some time and am very comfortable working with the DOM for AJAX and programming interactivity.

However, I recently started a new job that uses ASP.NET Web Forms, and I was wondering if there is any way to rely on using jquery for all my AJAX and DOM manipulation as opposed to using POST backs.

I really wish I could use ASP.NET MVC, but I was hoping to find a good middle-ground.
I want to have jQuery, plugins and my own client-side code to handle DOM manipulation once the page is loaded.

I was thinking I could use simple controls like repeaters to write out my HTML. I guess I want to avoid all the bloated code the web forms engine adds and use the unobtrusive approach of separating front-end with the back-end better.

Hope my question makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: I do exactly this... I use the aspx pages to generate html. Then I have a set of webservices that handle all of the communication from Javascript. This keeps my UI and logic seperate. Also, to replace the update panel, I have aspx pages that are only html snippets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joe Stagner who made a lot of training videos about the Ajax Control Tookit has started an ambitioned project on [his blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/misfit-geek-podcast-episode-2-does-vb-have-a-future-lisa-feigenbaum/) to replace the features of the Toolkit by JQuery alternatives for ASP.NET webforms projects:

> I’ll be doing jQuery alternatives for
> ALL my Microsoft Ajax and Ajax control
> toolkit videos.

I think the first post he made about this project is this one:

[http://www.misfitgeek.com/asp-net-rounded-corners-jquery/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/misfit-geek-podcast-episode-2-does-vb-have-a-future-lisa-feigenbaum/)

All other blogs he published in the meantime can probably easiest be found under his "act" tag or "jquery" category (they likely will overlap):

[http://www.misfitgeek.com/tag/act/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/misfit-geek-podcast-episode-2-does-vb-have-a-future-lisa-feigenbaum/)

[http://www.misfitgeek.com/category/jquery/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/misfit-geek-podcast-episode-2-does-vb-have-a-future-lisa-feigenbaum/)

**Edit**

(Links fixed to new domain.)

Update: Joe Stagner is not working anymore at Microsoft. The project mentioned above is only a fragment and will probably never be finished.

> *NOTE (18/02/2022): The above links appear to have either expired or been hacked.  I've modified them to point to Joe Stagner's Microsoft blog, instead, despite his not working there any longer.*

Answer (score 1):

We use `web forms` where I work, and I end up using ALOT of `web methods`. I followed this way of doing it and it works out pretty well.

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Basically you can call the `web method` from JQuery's ajax call like so

```
url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName"
```

It got rid of having to use a ton of `updatepanels` and having needless `postbacks`.

Answer (score 1):

You can most certainly use JQuery with ASP.Net. One thing I have noticed is that if you use Updatepanels as well as JQuery, things may collide. Like in the [JQuery Dialog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shayf/archive/2009/02/20/a-bad-of-roses-jquery-ui-dialog-and-asp-net-ajax.aspx) . Barring that,  I found this [link](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/) to be useful when I started off with JQuery in web forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Jquery to do your Ajax (using the static page methods or  a web service) and DOM manipulation.

But I don't think you can completely avoid posting back, which is how web form post data back to server.